# How to pass List<> to Javascript and display in combobox c#

Tags: javascript, c#, list, combobox

I have a List that store some records that filtered from database.
I have no idea on Javascript. Is anyone can teach me on how to pass the List to Javascript and display it in combo box?
P/S: I want the combobox text field to store Name (allow user to see) and the value field to store nameId (hidden from user).

My c# code behind is as follow:

```
public static List<bllControls> getPropertyTypeByPhaseId(int prmPhaseId)
{
    bllControls clsControls = new bllControls();
    List<bllControls> lstControls = new List<bllControls>();
    lstControls = clsControls.PropertyTypeSource(prmPhaseId);

    return lstControls;
}
```

While my Javascript code is as follow:

```
function onSelectedPhase(comboPhase) {
        var phaseId = comboPhase.GetValue();
        PageMethods.getPropertyTypeByPhaseId(phaseId, onSuccess, onFailed);
        function onSuccess(oaCompProj) {
            //here should loop the List and then store in combobox
        }
        function onFailed(oaCompProj) { alert('Failed to get Company and Project info'); }
    }
```

my combobox id is ddlProperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just provide the javascript logic to add element in combo box as below.

```
var cb = document.getElementById("comboBoxId"); // combo box widget
var lstItem = [
    {
        nameId: 1,
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        nameId: 2,
        name: "Doh"
    }
]; 

// Solution 1
for(var i = 0; i < lstItem.length; i++) {
    var item = lstItem[i];
    var elem = document.createElement("option");
    elem.textContent = item.name;
    elem.value = item.nameId;
    cb.appendChild(elem);
}​

// Solution 2  if var lstItem = ['0001@ABC', '0002@DEF'];
for(var i = 0; i < lstItem.length; i++) {
    var item = lstItem[i].split('@');
    var elem = document.createElement("option");
    elem.textContent = item[1]; // for character after '@' e.g. ABC or DEF
    elem.value = item[0]; // for character before '@' e.g. 0001 or 0002
    cb.appendChild(elem);
}​
```

Please adopt this concept after you retrieve data from database.
Enjoy it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to ask 1 more question:

what if my lstItem is store in this format("0001@ABC")
how to split the lstItem by using '@' syombol and store into the combobox?

Comment: var a = '0001@ABC';  var sptItem = a.split('@');   var nameId = sptItem[0]; var name = sptItem[1];

Comment: @chonglt I've just edit my answer for you question. Please see the solution 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: @chonglt Welcome, Can you vote and mark my answer as the best, Please?